# How to pass a php variable into interpolated value

Tags: php, html, angularjs, interpolation

I want to dynmically change the name inside the {{ }}. here is my code and I want $firstEle that keeps changing inside the {{}}. I am new to angularjs!

```
 public $testArr = array(
    array("PersonID", 1, 1, 'yes' ,"number", 'yes', 'on'),
    array("LastName", 1, 1, 'no' ,"text", 'yes', 'on'),
    array("FirstName", 2, 1, 'no' ,"text", 'yes', 'off')
);

foreach($testArr as $disp)
        {
            if($disp[6] === 'on')
            {
                $firstEle= $disp[0];
                echo <<<HTML
                <div style="display: inline-block; width: 25%; padding: 
20px;" >{{row.$firstEle}}</div>
                <button class="btn btn-success text-right" data-ng- 
click="showFilled(row)">EDIT</button>
HTML;

            }
        }
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _dynamically change_. Is this "as the user types"? Is it "from a known list'? or something else. This can make a huge difference to how something like this would be coded.

Comment: you should be doing this on the angular side, not with php

Comment: This seems to work already, if I understand correctly what you're trying to do https://3v4l.org/En5JX But I agree with @IdontDownVote, this doesn't seem like the right way to go about it.